# Changing Search View back icon?

Tags: android

I am using AppCompat action bar and i want to change the back icon of the searchview I use in the action bar. I searched but i couldn't find a solution.

I have tried setting the icon in the style :

`<item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/myBackButton</item>`

but I want to set another one programmatically when the user selects the search view.
Any ideas on how I can do it?

Answer (score 5):

To customize SearchView "up" icon, you can use style attribute:

```
collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_discard_icon"
```

in your Toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:collapseIcon="@drawable/ic_discard_icon"/>
```

Or you can move this attribute into Toolbar style. As you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of the back icon like this

```
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initToolbar();
}

private void initToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tbMaster);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.base_color));
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.image);
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewParent android.view.View.getParent()' on a null object reference

Comment: I edited my answer for AppCompat toolbar, can you try this one?

Comment: i am not using a toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    // get the parent view of home (app icon) imageview
    ViewGroup home = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent();
    // get the first child (up imageview)
    ( (ImageView) home.getChildAt(0) )
        // change the icon according to your needs
        .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_icon_up));
} else {
    // get the up imageview directly with R.id.up
    ( (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.up) )
        .setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_icon_up));
}
```

Comment: ViewGroup home = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.home).getParent(); gives nullPointerException. Where do i have to call it?

Comment: Do you have a toolbar or actionbar?

Comment: @IvanoDonadi, try getting home like this: `ViewGroup home = findViewById(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.id.home : android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home);`